# SQL Query: Get rows where value of certain column is maximum

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

Here is example of data I'm dealing with:

`Ei` (first column) is the primary key.

```
 E0 S0 DT0 V1
 E1 S1 DT1 V1
 E2 S1 DT2 V1
 E3 S1 DT3 V3
```

I am trying to filter this to get:

```
 E0 S0 DT0 V1
 E3 S1 DT3 V3
```

Basically, get rows such that if they have same `Si` then choose the row with highest/greatest `Vi`. `Vi` is of the form w.xy.z (where w, x, y, z are whole numbers).

I don't know how I can do this. Any pointers?

Comment: What flavor of sql are we talking about?  MySQL? 2008R2? 2014?

Comment: I am running Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select ei, si, dti, vi from (
    select ei, si, dti, vi,
           row_number() over(partition by si order by vi desc) rw
    from your_tab
) as t where rw = 1;
```

You can use analytic functions (ROW_NUMBER in this case).

Analytic functions are similar to aggregate functions as they are applied to a group of rows. But they return one value for each row.

`PARTITION BY` defines a group, `ORDER BY` defines the ordering inside the group

ROW_NUMBER assigns a sequential row number for each row in the group according to the ORDER BY (for each distinct value of `si` the first row number is 1)

If you need to retrieve the result with ties, you can use RANK / DENSE_RANK functions. They assign the same row number to the rows which have an equal "weight".

For example

```
E0 S0 DT0 V1
E1 S1 DT1 V1
E2 S1 DT2 V1
E3 S1 DT3 V3
E4 S1 DT4 V3
```

RANK / DENSE_RANK would return

```
E0 S0 DT0 V1
E3 S1 DT3 V3
E4 S1 DT4 V3
```

ROW_NUMBER

```
E0 S0 DT0 V1
E3 S1 DT3 V3 (or E4 S1 DT4 V3)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, señor.

Comment: Just a small correction, the query written as is throws a syntax error. 'select ei, si, dti, vi from ( select ei, si, dti, vi, row_number() over(partition by si order by vi desc) rw from your_tab ) as T where rw = 1;' fixes it.

Comment: @NGambit Thanks, I've updated the answer. Some databases require an alias for every inline view.